# Unable to authenticate correctly with custom django authentication backend

Tags: django-authentication, django-login, login-required

I have a custom authentication backend that should authenticate tutors as they login. The issue is that the authentication backend returns a user object with correct credentials, but the `@login_required` decorator receives `None` for `request.user.is_authenticated`. So the loop goes from login to login endlessly. I tried printing the `session_key` across requests, and it is the same.

**FILES**

**Authentication Backend**

```py
class TutorAuthBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username_or_email=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        print(f"Attempting to authenticate: {username_or_email}")
        try:
            validate_email(username_or_email)
            is_valid_email_format = True
        except ValidationError:
            is_valid_email_format = False

        auth_type = 'email__iexact' if is_valid_email_format else 'username__iexact'
        auth_param = {auth_type: username_or_email}

        try:
            tutor = Tutor.objects.get(**auth_param)
            if tutor.check_password(password):
                print(f"Authenticated: {tutor}")
                return tutor
        except Tutor.DoesNotExist:
            pass

        return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        """
        Returns the tutor object using the given user_id.
        """
        try:
            return Tutor.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except Tutor.DoesNotExist:
            return None


def tutor_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username_or_email = request.POST.get('username_or_email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        tutor = TutorAuthBackend().authenticate(request, username_or_email=username_or_email, password=password)
        if tutor:
            login(request, tutor, backend='tutor.backends.TutorAuthBackend')
            messages.success(request, "You're Logged In")
            if tutor.profile_picture:
                print("Profile Picture:", tutor.profile_picture.url)
                return redirect('tutor_dashboard', tutor_id=tutor.id)
            return redirect('tutor_profile')
        else:
            tutor_exists = Tutor.objects.filter(username=username_or_email).exists()
            if tutor_exists:
                messages.error(request, 'Incorrect Password')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'User Not Found')
            return render(request, 'tutor/tutor_login.html', context={'username_or_email': username_or_email})
    else:
        return render(request, 'tutor/tutor_login.html')
```

First, I tried to print out how the view communicates with the authentication backend by printing before and after the backend returns something. The backend returns a valid authenticated user. In the dashboard view, I printed request.user.is_authenticated() and it returns false, I printed the request.user and it returned AnonymousUser. I tried to know if the session was the problem by increasing the SESSION_COOKIE_AGE to 7 days and explicitly specifying the SESSION_ENGINE to django.contrib.sessions.backends.db in settings.py. I have also tried to log the session_key for each user looping the login page, and it appears consistent. I couldn't make helpful meaning from the Django docs too. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. The problem was of naming convention. My custom backend was named `tutor_backends.py` rather than `backends.py`.It seems Django doesn't understand any custom backend that is not exactly named `backends.py`.
So even though the logic is correct and the backend authenticates, the authentication does not persist to session hence, `@login_required` which checks is a session user `is_authenticated` receives an `False` beccause auths doesn't persist to session. I hope this helps someone. Unfortunately, I didn't see that spelt out in the docs.